# У LoadBalancer-а адрес EXTERNAL-IP бесконечно pending

Tags: kubernetes, yandex-cloud

Разбирал полгода назад лекции по Kubernetes для чайников, всё получалось. Сейчас спустя некоторое время пытаюсь освежить знания, но почему-то появились ошибки.

Зарегистрирован в **облаке YandexCloud**. Платёжный аккаунт в статусе **Active**.

Конфиг файл такой:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

metadata:
  name: my-web-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-k8s-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 3

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      project: app1

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        project: app1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app1-web
          image: adv4000/k8sphp:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service

metadata:
  name: my-single-pod-service
  labels:
    env: prod
    owner: AlexVld

spec:
  selector:
    project: app1
  ports:
    - name: app-listener
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Далее запускаю данный конфиг, чтобы создать **поды**, **деплоймент** и **сервис**:
`kubectl apply -f service-1-loadbalancer-single.yaml`

Смотрю что получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тут проблема с **сервисом**. Для сервиса **my-single-pod-service** типа **LoadBalancer** должно выставиться значение у **External-IP**. Я это значение должен вставить в браузер и увидеть простенькое приложение на php. Но у меня **pending** бесконечно долго и не дождусь как установится.

Причём, как я писал в начале, я это всё уже проделывал несколько месяцев назад. И сейчас делаю по своим старым записям в блокноте. Раньше этой проблемы не было, сейчас появилась. Может в самом сервисе **YandexCloud** какие-то изменения произошли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге нашёл в документации Яндекс.Облака, что при создании кластера нужны сервисные аккаунты с ролями **editor** и **container-registry.images.puller** , либо можно обе эти роли объединить в одном сервисном аккаунте.

Создал правильный сервисный аккаунт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И заново создал кластер и узлы, указывая именно этот аккаунт. И в итоге всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Роль `editor` довольно широкая и не всегда хочется выдавать её. На самом деле для создания **внешнего** балансировщика нагрузки не хватало роли `vpc.publicAdmin`. Именно она позволяет создавать и удалять публичные IP-адреса. https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/iam/concepts/access-control/roles#vpc-public-admin